# Can MySQL GTIDs be used in a master-master topology?

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

When using coordinate based replication, it was possible in MySQL to have each of two nodes replicating off the other in a master-master topology.

**With the introduction of GTID's in MySQL 5.6, can this same topology be used in the same way when GTID replication is enabled?**

I don't immediately see any reason why not, but I can't find any info online about it and I just don't want to discover a few weeks later a bunch of weird corruption issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql documentation on [restrictions in replication with GTID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-gtids-restrictions.html) do not mention that master - master replication is not allowed. I also found a [Percona blog entry](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/09/05/using-mysql-5-6-global-transaction-ids-gtids-in-production-qa/) that explicitly says that this is allowed:

> Q: Does GTID provide any benefit to master-master replication? If yes,
>   how? Q: Is ACTIVE ACTIVE MASTER MASTER successful in MySQL with GTID?
>
> A: GTIDs don’t change the nature of MySQL replication: for instance it
>   is still asynchronous and if you write on both masters in a
>   master-master setup, there is still no write conflict detection
>   mechanism. The main benefit of GTIDs is that any change of the
>   replication topology is easy because you no longer need to run complex
>   calculations to find the right binlog positions when connecting a
>   slave to a new master. So master-master replication can be configured
>   with GTIDs, it does not provide a lot of benefits compared to
>   position-based replication as you will never change the replication
>   topology. And having a setup where both masters receive writes is
>   still not recommended with GTIDs.